# Getting the exact edit box dimensions for the given text

Tags: windows, winapi, controls

I need to be able to determine the size of the edit box according to the text I have, and a maximum width.
There are similar questions and answers, which suggest `GetTextExtentPoint32` or `DrawTextEx`.

`GetTextExtentPoint32` doesn't support multiline edit controls, so it doesn't fit.

`DrawTextEx` kind of works, but sometimes the edit box turns out to be larger than necessary, and, what's worse, sometimes it's too small.

Then there's `EM_GETRECT` and `EM_GETMARGINS`. I'm not sure whether I should use one of them, or maybe both.

What is the most accurate method for calculating the size? This stuff is more complicated then it should be... and I prefer not to resort to reading the source code of Wine or ReactOS.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here's my code and a concrete example:

```
bool AutoSizeEditControl(CEdit window, LPCTSTR lpszString, int *pnWidth, int *pnHeight, int nMaxWidth = INT_MAX)
{
    CFontHandle pEdtFont = window.GetFont();
    if(!pEdtFont)
        return false;

    CClientDC oDC{ window };
    CFontHandle pOldFont = oDC.SelectFont(pEdtFont);

    CRect rc{ 0, 0, nMaxWidth, 0 };
    oDC.DrawTextEx((LPTSTR)lpszString, -1, &rc, DT_CALCRECT | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK);

    oDC.SelectFont(pOldFont);

    ::AdjustWindowRectEx(&rc, window.GetStyle(), (!(window.GetStyle() & WS_CHILD) && (window.GetMenu() != NULL)), window.GetExStyle());

    UINT nLeftMargin, nRightMargin;
    window.GetMargins(nLeftMargin, nRightMargin);

    if(pnWidth)
        *pnWidth = rc.Width() + nLeftMargin + nRightMargin;

    if(pnHeight)
        *pnHeight = rc.Height();

    return true;
}
```

I call it with `nMaxWidth` = 143 and the following text (below), and get `nHeight` = 153, `nWidth` = 95. But the numbers are too small for the text to fit, on both axes.

The text (two lines):

```
Shopping
https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=winapi+resize+edit+control+to+text+size&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMyNaWxZjLAhUiLZoKHQcoDqUQ_AUICigE
```

**Edit 2**

I found out that the word wrapping algorithm of `DrawTextEx` and of the exit control are different. For example, the edit control wraps on `?`, `DrawTextEx` doesn't. What can be done about it?

Comment: DrawText is the way to do it, perhaps add your current code. The sometimes too big/small bug can be a symptom of forgetting to make sure the font used with dt_calrect is the same as the edit controls.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the reply, I added more details

Comment: The edit control allows arbitrary word break logic (`EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC`) which `DrawText` does not, so it's not that surprising that the default logic is also different to `DrawText` in some way. I suspect your only solution is to mimic the word break behaviour, split the string up into individual lines and do the calculation on a per-line basis.

Comment: Note that `EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC` only applies to RichEdit controls (`CRichEditCtrl`), not to Edit controls (`CEdit`).

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is surprising at least because `DrawTextEx` has a flag named `DT_EDITCONTROL`, which implies that it has something to do with the edit control. Perhaps it's possible to change the word breaking logic, but at least the default could have been the same.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Note yourself, *"You can send this message to either an edit control or a rich edit control."*

Comment: @Paul `DT_EDITCONTROL` invokes specific behaviour: *Specifically, the average character width is calculated in the same manner as for an edit control, and the function does not display a partially visible last line.*. Doesn't say anything about word break.